# Mailto is opening up options

Tags: html, forms, indexing, submit, mailto

When I insert my into my website and I submit the form Windows 8 pops up a little menu and asks how I want to open this (mailto)

This is my code for the form

```
 <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="mailto:myemail">  
 <div id="subscribe">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address...">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The mailto is the part i'm having problems with. Any help would be great.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. Perhaps consider revising this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a default program for your operating system to email from - this is not something that you can fix through HTML. Whoever is going to your webpage will see a different dialog box if they haven't already configured their default mailto options.

You will not be able to make it automatically send an email through HTML alone- you will have to use a server-side language such as PHP if this is what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. If I was to add this code to the website http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php and was to only include the email part will I just have to erase the name part and so forth or does the entire code have to rewritten?

Comment: Yeah I think that you could use that as the basis for your PHP if you removed the unnecessary parts that you don't want to collect :)